# Jsoup select method return null, when the tag is exists in the webpage

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to select tag `<div class=kcm-read-text>` in this [web](http://bisniskeuangan.kompas.com/read/2016/02/11/181807726/Kembangkan.Branchless.Banking.BNI.Gandeng.Pos.Indonesia).

`Jsoup` can get the text inside that tag. But when I want to get the text inside tag `<div class=kcm-read-text>` from [here](http://regional.kompas.com/read/xml/2015/11/10/10473481/Terima.Uang.Nyasar.Rp.5.1.Miliar.Nasabah.BNI.Habiskan.Rp.2.2.Miliar) it return null. I don't know why. I'm trying to figure it out but still don't know the reason.

This is my code

```
Document dok = Jsoup.connect(URL).timeout(0).get();
Element isiBerita = dok.select("div.kcm-read-text").first();
```

I also try to use this but return the same result:

```
Element isiBerita = dok.select("div[class~=kcm-read-text]").first();`
```

Though both have the same html format, just have different contents.

Thanks for your help before.

Comment: Change user agent like `Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").timeout(...`

Comment: wow, thanks so much. I't works because of userAgent (y)(y)(y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response provided by [saka1029](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4910279/saka1029)

> Change user agent like Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").timeout(...